# Reduce Rows to a map struct in hsql

Tags: hadoop, hive

New to hadoop/ hive and need to reduce a set of rows down into a map datatype as follows;

**From**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Jeff | Smith |
| Steve | Brown |

**To**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Jeff":"Smith"}, { "Steve" : "Brown} |

Answer (score 1):

```
with myTable as (
  select 'Jeff' as Col1, 'Smith' as Col2 union
  select 'Steve' as Col1, 'Brown' as Col2
)  -- test data
SELECT CONCAT(
  CONCAT_WS(', ', COLLECT_LIST(json_pair))
) as json_result
FROM (
  SELECT concat('{"', col1, '":"', col2, '"}') as json_pair
  FROM myTable
) t;
```

```
+--------------------------------------+
|           json_result                |
+--------------------------------------+
| {"Jeff":"Smith"},{"Steve":"Brown"}   |
+--------------------------------------+
```